# Find surface area of a minor arc rotated around a chord

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

Let $A$ and $B$ be points on a circle centered at $O$ with radius $R,$ and let $\angle AOB = 2 \alpha \le \pi.$ Minor arc $AB$ is rotated about chord $\overline{AB}.$ Find the surface area of the resulting solid in terms of $R$ and $\alpha.$ This question has been asked before here: [Finding the surface area of a solid formed by the rotation of an arc about a chord](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133362/finding-the-surface-area-of-a-solid-formed-by-the-rotation-of-an-arc-about-a-cho) but it hasn't gotten any answers since it was asked.

Could someone please help me answer it?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your attempt?

Comment: @MathLover I kinda started by looking at the isosceles triangle ABO. With length R, we can find the triangle's height, which is R sin(alpha). -R sin (alpha) and R sin (alpha) will be the bounds for the integral. (I assumed the circle was positioned at (0,0)). I need help continuing though.

Comment: you should provide all details in the question instead of in comments and a diagram always helps. If the chord $AB$ is perpendicular to x-axis, can you find the horizontal distance from $AB$ to the circle at any given $y$? That is the main step.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**...consider finding the equation of a circle radius $R$ whose centre has coordinates $(0,-R\cos\alpha)$.

The section of this circle above the $x$ axis is rotated about the $x$ axis.

If you find $y$ in terms of $x$ you will be able to arrive at $$1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{R^2}{R^2-x^2}$$

You can then use the standard integral formula for surface area, with appropriate limits.