# Finding the surface area of a minor arc rotated over a chord

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $A$ and $B$ be points on a circle centered at $O$ with radius $R,$ and let $\angle AOB = 2 \alpha \le \pi.$ Minor arc $AB$ is rotated about chord $\overline{AB}.$ Find the surface area of the resulting solid in terms of $R$ and $\alpha.$

> [image]

This has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263961/find-surface-area-of-a-minor-arc-rotated-around-a-chord). However, it has not received an answer yet. I found the distance between the arc and the chord to be $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2} - R \cos \alpha.$ From this, using the formula for surface area in Calculus, I simplified the answer to,
$$2\pi\int_{-R\sin\alpha}^{R\sin\alpha}\left(\sqrt{R^2 - x^2} - R\cos\alpha\right)\cdot R\sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2 - x^2}}\, dx.$$

I do not know how to simplify this further, or whether it is even correct so far. Can someone please help me out with the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes your work is correct. Integrals are standard integrals. Just use the integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}} = \arcsin \left(\frac{x}{R}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's compute the formula you gave.

Noting that
$$\int_{-R\sin(\alpha)}^{R\sin(\alpha)}\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\,R\,\sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2-x^2}}\,dx=2R^2\sin(\alpha),$$
and
$$\int_{-R\sin(\alpha)}^{R\sin(\alpha)}R\cos(\alpha)\,R\,\sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2-x^2}}\,dx=R^2\cos(\alpha)\int_{-R\sin(\alpha)}^{R\sin(\alpha)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\,dx.$$
Using change of variable, we assume $x=R\sin(t)$ where $t\in[-\alpha,\alpha]$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{-R\sin(\alpha)}^{R\sin(\alpha)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\,dx&=\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-R^2\sin^2(t)}}\,R\cos(t)\,dt=2\alpha.
\end{align*}
Combine these result and plug into the formula you gave, we yield,
$$S=2\pi\,\left(2R^2\sin(\alpha)-2R^2\alpha\cos(\alpha)\right)=4\pi R^2\big(\sin(\alpha)-\alpha\cos(\alpha)\big).$$

Comment: Using $V$ for area is not a very intuitive choice.

Comment: My bad, it is edited now.